# Why when setting active true the canvas object it's not setting active true also the childs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text dialogueText;
    public Text nameText;
    public float sentencesSwitchDuration;
    public bool animateSentenceChars = false;
    public GameObject canvas;
    public static bool dialogueEnded = false;
    public ConversationTrigger trigger;

    private Queue<string> sentence;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        sentence = new Queue<string>();
    }

    public void StartDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
    {
        dialogueEnded = false;

        canvas.SetActive(true);

        nameText.text = dialogue.Name;

        if(sentence == null)
            sentence = new Queue<string>();

        sentence.Clear();
        foreach (string sentence in dialogue.Sentences)
        {
            this.sentence.Enqueue(sentence);
        }

        DisplayNextSentence();
    }

    public void DisplayNextSentence()
    {
        if (this.sentence.Count == 0)
        {
            EndDialogue();
            return;
        }

        string sentence = this.sentence.Dequeue();
        dialogueText.text = sentence;

        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(DisplayNextSentenceWithDelay(sentence));
    }

    public IEnumerator DisplayNextSentenceWithDelay(string sentence)
    {
        if (animateSentenceChars)
        {
            dialogueText.text = "";
            foreach (char letter in sentence.ToCharArray())
            {
                dialogueText.text += letter;
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sentencesSwitchDuration);
        DisplayNextSentence();
    }

    private void EndDialogue()
    {
        dialogueEnded = true;
    }
}
```

I'm doing :

```
canvas.SetActive(true);
```

The result is that Dialogue GUI is active but the childs of it are not. And I want to active also the childs. And when settings active false also the childs too.

The game start when Dialogue GUI is active false not active. Then after some seconds in the game the Dialogue GUI get active true but not the childs :

[image: Childs of Dialogue GUI are not active]

Comment: Check that they are active by default, they will keep their current status regardless of how the parent changes. (Just make sure they are active within the parent and toggle all by toggling the parent if you want them all to toggle together)

Comment: in short: because this is not what `SetActive` is used for .. it only applies to the object itself, not the children

Comment: while deactivating a parent hides the children, if all the children are deactive activating the parent doesnt waken all the children

Comment: @akaBase Right. this is working thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short: because this is not what [`SetActive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) is used for .. **it only applies to the object itself**, not the children.

---

You seem to deactivate each and every child in your scene or prefab and then you only activate the main `Canvas` object.

So the most trivial solution is: Do not disable any objects in the scene, but **only the `Canvas` object** itself.

---

A quick workaround would of course be setting active all child objects recursively though I wouldn't recommend to go that way

```
// returns all recursive children transforms including this transform as well
// by passing true you also get disabled and inactive components
foreach(var obj in GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true))
{
    obj.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

this is of course not very efficient ;)